# downloading failed from github using Git LFS

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I tried to use git clone to download repository from [this repository](https://github.com/eshijia/knowledge-graph-keras.git). When I used

```
git clone https://github.com/eshijia/knowledge-graph-keras.git
```

I get the following error :

```
Error downloading object: data/freebase15k/freebase_15k-id2entity.pkl (d40c058):                                                             Smudge error: Error downloading data/freebase15k/freebase_15k-id2entity.pkl (d4                        0c05819ce4431249d27970c5c6abbd4a09b9616f3321c5082227be7a5eea0d): LFS: Get https:                                                             //github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com/alambic/media/127872792/d4/0c/d40c05819ce4431249 d27970c5c6abbd4a09b9616f3321c5082227be7a5eea0d?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256& X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIMWPLRQEC4XCWWPA%2F20180619%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request &X-Amz-Date=20180619T071649Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Signature=e4c596e3046463c5 0dc27e23ca22fbb036a9aa25f48449467af2b3b71117e8da&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_ id=0&token=1: dial tcp 219.76.4.4:443: connectex: A connection attempt failed be                                                              cause the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or es                                                            tablished connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Errors logged to C:\Users\User\Desktop\Learning Materials\programming\python_cod                                       e\DL\knowledge-graph-keras\.git\lfs\logs\20180619T151710.7131223.log Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log. error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed fatal: data/freebase15k/freebase_15k-id2entity.pkl: smudge filter lfs failed warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed. You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status' and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

However, if I downloaded the `data/freebase15k/freebase_15k-id2entity.pkl` directly from the original github page, the pkl file could be downloaded well.

Any solution for this?

PS: my git version is `2.17.1.windows.2`

Comment: Can you execute `git-lfs filter-process`?

Comment: I download correctly

Comment: Did you download it by git clone ?

Comment: git clone https://github.com/eshijia/knowledge-graph-keras.git
Cloning into 'knowledge-graph-keras'...
remote: Counting objects: 134, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (71/71), done.
....
Filtering content: 100% (16/16), 272.59 MiB | 350.00 KiB/s, done.

Comment: It must be from your credentials

Comment: You have tried to download again it may be a connection failure

Comment: I have tried to download it several times in my company. Maybe it's because of the internal connection problem.

Comment: But I look for alternatives for the download and I download it

Comment: I could try downloading it at home. Besides that, what do you suggest me to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Rewiev the fails the GIT-LFS

## Connection

A solution can be caused by a bad connection.

## Bad installation of Git LFS

There’s an issue with the LFS install on your drive. The only way I was able to solve it was to:

• Remove Repos on HDD that are failing. Uninstall any instances of git-lfs

• Install git-lfs for windows

• Verify in the repo dropdown in SourceTree that git-lfs in initialized

• Open up Git shell, and navigate to local repo just cloned

• Type git lfs install

• Type git pull

• Type git lfs pull

## Alternatives if no immediate solution is found

### Download by parts

La web [minhaskamal.github.io](https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home) allows you to download the desired folder of a project, you just have to indicate the url and that's it, it's convenient and easy.[image: web gitdown]

### Download as zip from github

Another alternative will be to download from the same repository:

```
Clone > Download Zip
```

[image: downloadzipgithub]

### Third-party software

You can also use it with:

- IDE that supports Git and where you can try to download the repository.
- GUI Clients: [GIT download/gui/](http://%20https://git-scm.com/download/gui/linux)